# event delegate not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a template inside my click event which i insert after the crurrent table row but the problem is when you click on the newly added template which has a event button class called .add the event dies and  doesn't work anymore it only works once when the page loads the template

```
$('.variations_grid tr td').delegate('.add', 'click', function(e) {
    $(this).closest('tr').after(template);
    //the buttons int the template don't work on click event
});

var template = '<tr>';
template += '<td class="white-space:nowrap">';
template +=     '<input type="hidden" name="variationsid" value="1" />';
template +=     '<button class="btn btn-default btn-block add" type="button">&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>&nbsp;</button>';
template +=     '<button class="btn btn-default btn-block remove" type="button">&nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign"></span>&nbsp;</button>';
template += '</td>';
template += '<tr>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With event delegation, the only thing to respect is that DOM elements on which the handlers were put must not be replaced. Therefore, you have to choose the closest possible container that will not be replaced.

For example, if you are replacing or adding new `<tr>` or `<td>` tags, dont bind event handlers on those or the delegation will not work.

Try this (I replaced `delegate` with `on` since `delegate` is deprecated now):

```
$('.variations_grid').on('click', '.add', function(e) {
    //your logic
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you're help . I learned something from you're answer I'll remember it from now on thanks again

Comment: Yeah that method works as well thanks for you're help